# How to get an IFrame src attribute value from ASP.Net code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

on ASP.Net code behind page i have generated the source and now i want to get that value of src attribute of iframe on html page?

Comment: src="<%=this.codebehindfunction() %>"

Answer (score 1):

on page:

```
<iframe runat="server" src="test" id="myFrame"></iframe>
```

on code behind:

```
string source = myFrame.Attributes["src"];
```